# A and B have equal chances of winning a single game. A wants n games and B wants n+1 games to win the match. find the odds in favour of A

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am stuck with this question can someone please give me a hint, how to go about this one. Is the total number of matches 2n and 2n +1?, I'm confused by this one

Comment: start with $n =1$ - what are the odds to win on the first round and what are the odds for win on the second match?

Comment: @Jneven Please can you elaborate a little more , both of them have the same probability if winning the match, but the total no of matches has not been mentioned

Comment: The match will have a random number of games.  It might be as low as $n$ games or as many as $2n$ games, depending on how the early games turn out.

Answer (score 1):

One of the hard parts of this problem is that the total number of games can be as small as $n$ (if A wins all $n$ of them) or as large as $2n$ (if the wins alternate B,A,B,A,..., for example).

We can avoid this by extending the match to $2n$ games, even if the winner has already been determined. That way:

- One player is guaranteed to satisfy their victory condition: whenever neither A nor B has won yet, the total number of games is at most $(n-1) + n = 2n-1$.
- However, both players cannot have satisfied their victory conditions: for that, we need at least $n + (n+1) = 2n+1$ games.

So whoever has the required number of wins after $2n$ games was the one to reach their target first, and win the match.

After the number of games is fixed, you can solve the problem with binomial probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints to get you started.  Half the time, player B wins the first game, and both players need $n$ games to win.  In this case, they each have probability of winning $\frac12$ so this case contributes $\frac14$ to B's probability of winning.

One quarter of the time, B loses the first game, but wins the second.  This brings us to the case where B need $n$ games and A needs $n-1$ so if we were doing it by induction we could substitute the probability from the $n-1$ case.

The other quarter of the time, A wins the first two games, so that B needs $n+1$ games and A needs $n-2$.  It's clear now that simple induction on $n$ is not going to work, because this is not one of the prior cases.  I think you will need to find a more general formula that works when A need $n$ games and B needs $m$ games.  I suggest that you make a number of small examples and see if you can guess then general formula.  Then you can prove it by recursion.